# Catching button press in while loop

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application which uses `MediaElement`.
I want to loop a certain part of a video. I have a `StartTime` and `EndTime` variables for the looping purpose. I tried `DispatcherTimer` for the looping purpose but it is too slow for the loop of less then 1 second. So I tried simple while loop as shown below.

```
while (true)
{
     if(!buttonPressed)
     {
          while (mePlayer.Position < loop.EndTime) ; //go till end of loop
          mePlayer.Position = loop.StartTime; //after reaching end of loop  start again
     }
}
```

with above code, even 0.5 second video loops properly but
the problem with the above approach is that once it entered infinite while loop it can not detect button press hence I am unable to stop the loop. So my question is that how to detect a button press in the while loop so that I can stop looping video and continue doing other task?

Comment: Why not just catch the event/detect change in bound property instead of a loop? And I haven't checked but surely player has PositionChanged event or such.

Comment: I just checked and I didn't find any PositionChanged Event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised you can't get any information about video playback progress. But you can go around this by combining `Task` and `Dispatcher` (because cross-threading) without blocking the UI, something like below.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource;
    private double _start;
    private double _stop;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        media.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
        Start = 0;

        media.MediaOpened += (sender, args) =>
        {
            Stop = (int)media.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds;
            SetEndPosition();
        };
        media.Source = new Uri("video.wmv", UriKind.Relative);
        media.Play();
    }

    private async void SetEndPosition()
    {
        _tokenSource?.Cancel();
        _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var token = _tokenSource.Token;

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                return;

            while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    double position = media.Position.TotalSeconds;
                    if (position >= Stop)
                        SetStartPosition();
                });
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }, token);
    }

    private void SetStartPosition()
    {
        media.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Start);
    }

    public double Start
    {
        get { return _start; }
        set { _start = value; OnPropertyChanged(); SetStartPosition(); }
    }

    public double Stop
    {
        get { return _stop; }
        set { _stop = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" 
        Height="422" 
        Width="450">
<Grid Margin="10">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="340" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <MediaElement Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,0,0,10" x:Name="media" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Start}"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Stop}"></TextBox>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: why not make the delegate `async` and `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100))` instead? there's no reason at all to block the thread.

Comment: The above code is working fine for loop. But what if I want to play video from point A to point B where A and B are user input. In this case I tried setting bot start time and end time as same but it is not working in that case.

Comment: Works fine, I update the code. Just be aware you need to do some modifications for a "real life" app.

Comment: Working fine now. Thank you Mikko Viitala.